# Matplotlib: Border line drawn on only the first bar after updating matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot with differing bar width. After I updated my Matplotlib to version 2.1.0 from 1.1.0. the same codes no longer work and I need to specify border color to have borders but the border is only drawn on the first bar.

Here are my codes:

```
import csv, os, os.path, math, pdb # pdb.set_trace()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = np.array(x)
bar_width = [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05]

data = np.array([1.6, 9.4, 10.1, 4.7, 6, 3.5])
plt.bar(x - bar_width, data, color = 'b', edgecolor = 'r')
plt.show()
```

This is what I get.

[image]

I must be missing something really basic but if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the duplicate on how to fix this until the new version comes out.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I searched before I asked this question but I did not find that post so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Matplotlib 2.1, see:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9496

Should be fixed in the 2.1.1 release of Matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was unfortunate that I installed this specific version. Is 2.1.1 released yet? I cannot find where I can download it.

Comment: Looks like 2.1.1 is still in development: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/milestone/26, so either wait, downgrade, or temporarily fix it yourself in your local version (not sure if that is a good idea, but the fix is fairly simple: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9353/files)

Comment: The reason I downvoted this answer is that duplicate questions should not have their own answers. It is a motivation to provide the answer to the original post. (What is the reason for you downvote on my answer?)

Comment: I don't know all the SO questions by heart, so if this happens to be a duplicate question, it makes perfect sense to close it, but not to downvote a legitimate answer.

Comment: Downvote == "This answer is not useful"; and indeed it is not useful because it is hidden inside a duplicate (and potentially does not add anything to already present answers - but in this case there are two links and another one in the comment, so it might actually add value to the subject if provided to the original question.).

Comment: I am not very knowledgeable regarding this issue so if you think I should close this question, please let me know how I can do so. Thank you Bart for your helpful guidance!

Comment: @owl You do not have to do anything. The question is already closed as duplicate, so just leave it as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this as well.